# Android table with round border

Tags: android, tablelayout

How can I make a table with a round border, similar to the photo below, in Android?

[image: Round-bordered table]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

I think Androidbase linked to the wrong question... he asked a similar question recently, and here's the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379578/how-to-show-group-tableview-android/2381894#2381894) I gave him:

You can put a coloured background with rounded corners into a table by using a Shape background. Create such a shape in an XML file, put in your drawables folder.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="#99FFFFFF"/>
    <corners android:radius="30px"/>
    <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp" android:bottom="0dp" /> 
</shape>
```

For example the above creates a semi-transparent white background with 30px rounded corners. You set this to the table by using

```
android:background="@drawable/my_shape_file"
```

in the XML file where you defined your table layout.

Comment: can any suggest me how to remove rounded corner of button ... thnx

Comment: +1. this was awesome.  also, if you want to set it on your table row programatically instead (say if you're alternating background shapes) use:  tableRow.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_shape_file);  more info [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2414134/dynamically-get-drawables-by-id)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use a masking technique - overlay a mask image (any iOS-style background, with a transparent cutout in it) over a standard layout.

This way, the background of my layout is not linked directly to a bitmap, I can change it very easily.

I have an answer explaining that here: [Android XML rounded clipped corners](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8313096/383414)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar task recently so I decided to write a library for this purpose. Feel free to use it for your needs... https://github.com/vladexologija/GroupedTextView

[image: GroupedTextView]

Comment: But it doesn't horizontally align the text on the right with your current implementation, right? It seems like a TableView will be better to use for implementation.

Comment: It's all there on Github, change it to android:gravity="right" if you prefer right alignment.