# Android Table UI Elements

Tags: android, android-layout, tablelayout

This is more design oriented but I am trying to figure out if there is a UI element I could use for this or if it is a graphical image they used.

http://s2.postimage.org/8wpons46m/whmcs.png

I am looking at the body area where it shows the rounded containers seperated out by lines. I just started working on my first Android app but haven't been able to find anything that looks like that.

Thanks!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2379578/how-to-show-group-tableview-android) similar question.

Comment: But in this case, really seems like an image. The items are not aligned vertically on the rows.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a list view with a shape as backgound :

```
<ListView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp" 
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:padding="3dp" 
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_background_rounded_rectangle"/>
```

And the code for the drawable can be somewhat like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<solid 
    android:color="@color/color_white" />
<corners 
    android:radius="7dip" />
```